# Creating a dataframe from multiple lists with list names as column names

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 lists:

```
name = ['Robert']
age = ['25']
gender = ['m']
```

I want to create a dataframe like the one shown below(with name of the list as column names):

[image]

This is what I'm doing to get this dataframe :

```
data=pd.DataFrame([name,age,gender]).T
data.columns=['name','age','gender']
```

I want to know whether there is a better way of doing this

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf yeah ..but what I wanted was a more pythonic way of doing it

Comment: Nope just `name` , `age` and `gender`

Answer (score 2):

#### Dataframe from columns

Note the `pd.DataFrame` constructor accepts a dictionary of column labels mapped to lists of values. So you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': name, 'age': age, 'gender': gender'})
```

#### Dataframe from rows

Alternatively, you can feed rows using a list comprehension with `zip`. This creates a list of lists, each sublist representing a single row:

```
name = ['Robert']
age = ['25']
gender = ['m']

L = [list(row) for row in zip(name, age, gender)]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['name', 'age', 'gender'])

print(df)

     name age gender
0  Robert  25      m
```

The above can be written functionally using `map`:

```
L = list(map(list, zip(name, age, gender)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(name=['Robert'],age=['25'],gender=['m']))
```

[`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) takes `data` as first parameter which is: `numpy.ndarray` , `dict`, or `DataFrame`.

Considering that you don't have more variables than `name`, `age`, and `gender` defined, I think this might work:

```
not_my_data = set(dir())
# define your variables
name=['Robert']
age=['25']
gender=['m'].

my_data = set(dir()) - not_my_data

pd.DataFrame({k:globals()[k] for k in my_data})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

```
d = {'name':['Robert'],'age':['25'],'gender':['m']}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

**Option 2**
Form the `dict` on the fly -

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(name=['Robert'], age=['25'], gender=['m']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    name=['Robert']
    age=['25']
    gender=['m']
    data = pd.DataFrame({"name":name,"age":age,"gender":gender})
```